# evento onclick nao funciona no chrome!

Tags: javascript, html5

Não estou conseguindo executar um exercício transição. Tenho as *img* de lâmpada apagada e outra acesa e uma quebrada!
Até a acessa eu consegui, mas quando é pa, quebrar o código não funciona!

Eis aqui código​ fonte:

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste javascript </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script>
    function acendeLampada(){
    document.getElementById("Luz").src = "_imagens/Lampada-acesa.jpg ";
    }
    function apagaLampada() {
    document.getElementById("Luz").src = " _imagens/Lampada-apagada.jpg ";
    }
    function quebraLampada() {
    }
    document.getElementById("Luz").src = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg ";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Acenda a lâmpada</h1>
<img src="_imagens/Lampada-apagada.jpg" id="Luz" onmousemove="acendeLampada()" onmouseout=" apagaLampada()" onclick="quebra-Lampada()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cadê o evento onclick?

Comment: to aprendendo ainda a formular as perguntas.

Comment: Tranquilo. É um pouco complicado mesmo rs.

Comment: Bem-vindo Wellington Samuel, se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como e o porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Têm basicamente 2 erros no seu código:

**1. Ação fora da função:**

```
function quebraLampada() {
    }
    document.getElementById("Luz").src = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg ";
```

**Correto:**

```
function quebraLampada() {
    document.getElementById("Luz").src = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg ";
}
```

**2. Função inexistente na tag `<img>`:**

```
onclick="quebra-Lampada()"
```

**Correto:**

```
onclick="quebraLampada()"
```

**OUTROS PROBLEMAS:**

Embora possa funcionar, não é uma *boa prática* deixar estes espaços em branco no início ou fim de sequências como:

```
" _imagens/Lampada-apagada.jpg "; RUIM
"_imagens/Lampada-apagada.jpg"; BOM
```

Comment: DvD valew mano vc é foda tambm cara eu nao tinha percebido tao obvio  neh eu coloque fora dos colchetes depois so coloquei lá ai lampada quebrou quando cliquei man muito obrigado

Comment: @WellingtonSamuel Valeu cara! Não esqueça de marcar a resposta pra não ficar "solta" por aí! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que percebi, sua função quebraLampada esta com abrindo e fechando o {} na posição errada!

**ERRADO**

```
function quebraLampada() {
}

document.getElementById("Luz").src = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg ";
```

**CERTO**

```
function quebraLampada() {
 document.getElementById("Luz").src = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg ";
}
```

Comment: muiiito obrigadoo cara vc é fodao cara! vlw mesmo deu certo